# Automating Excel to save file as CSV and run live updates

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, csv, save-as, document-automation

For starters - I am raw and have limited skills, thus the guidance here is important to me.
We have to supply data to a 3rd party in CSV format. The data must be updated at frequent intervals with a timestamp. Some workbooks at 1 minute intervals and other at 30/60 minute intervals.
To ensure that data is permanently available I have done a little batch file to start the excel file.
Our normal method of collecting data is via excel.
I am able to get the data to update at at frequent intervals (10 seconds) courtesy Mr Google with a macro. The Macro also starts automatically on open event.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Range("A1:A1").Calculate
 Application.OnTime DateAdd("s", 10, Now), "Calculate_Range"
    
End Sub
```

I have however run into issues when trying to save this to CSV file - the guidelines found thus far does not help me to have this process run unattended. I have managed to get past the overwrite query, but when I tried the format acknowledgement it fails.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.Run "VBATest.xlsm!Calculate_Range"
    ChDir "E:\PI"
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="E:\PI\VBATest01.xlcsv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
                CreateBackup:=False
    Application.Run "VBATest.xlsm!Calculate_Range"

End Sub
```

#### What I need to accomplish is to:

1. *Run the excel file automatically - the batch file can be added to scheduler to restart this.*
2. *Update the values at preset intervals - the macro I have now, can run this.*
3. *Save sheet as CSV file automatically without intervention required (overwrite and format compatibility).*
4. *Restart the excel file - batch file in scheduler if there is now other better method.*

Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: welcome to superuser, nice first question with great effort behind it! regarding your questions: 1. just google for "schedule VBA macro" 3. try to record a macro when you save the file, that might help to understand how to do it. 4. I don't know how that's different from your first question. If you still have doubts maybe it worth to ask them as new question focusing only on one problem at a time.

Comment: can try adding `workbook.Settings.CheckCompatibility = false;` to your vba before saving as xlcsv